# How to create read-only field in View

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a form with 2 fields - `empno` and `name`. Both fill up with default value. When display in view, I want `empno` is read-only and `name` is editable.

In view creation, I am using `@leaveform.value.get.empno` to display ready-only and work fine. The problem only occur during insert with error `([NoSuchElementException: None.get])`.

Questions:

1. The problem is return error does not have value property. What else could I use to get the value?
2. Could I skip `@inputText` for read-only field?

Refer below my code:

```
// ***** CONTROLLER *****//

val leaveform = Form[LeaveModel](
      mapping(
          "empno" -> nonEmptyText,
          "name" -> nonEmptyText
      )((no, empno) => LeaveModel(empno, name))
      ((leave: LeaveModel) => Some(leave.empno, leave.name))
)

def create = withAuth { username => implicit request =>

  // Define default values
  val empno = "STUDENT"
  val name = ""

  // Set default values
  val filledForm = leaveform.fill(LeaveModel(empno,name))
  Ok(html.leave.form(filledForm))
}

def insert = Action (
    implicit request => {
        leaveform.bindFromRequest.fold(
            error => {
                BadRequest(html.leave.form(error)) // Question 1. Here is the error.
            },
            leave => {
               LeaveModel.insert(leave)
               Redirect(routes.indexController.index())
            }
        )  
      }
  )

// ***** VIEW START***** //
@(leaveform: Form[LeaveModel])
@leaveform.value.get.empno
@helper.form(
    action = (routes.LeaveController.update(oid)),
        'id -> "leaveform") {
            @inputText(leaveform("empno")) // Question 2. 
            @inputText(leaveform("name"))
        }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not mandatory to use the form helpers. If you use them you can pass the attribute `readonly` or style the field with CSS to make it look read only.

- Twitter bootstrap disabled by CSS:

  ```
  @inputText(
      editForm("createdOn"), 
      'id -> "createdOn", 
      'class -> "input-xlarge disabled", 
      '_label -> Messages("createdOn"), 
      '_help -> ""
  )
  ```
- Pass optional attribute: `readonly`

  ```
  @inputText(
      editForm("createdOn"), 
      'id -> "createdOn", 
      'class -> "input-xlarge", 
      '_label -> Messages("createdOn"), 
      'readonly -> "readonly", 
      '_help -> " This is read only"
  )
  ```
- You can also don't resend the field, but display its value:

  ```
  <span class="date">Created on: @editForm("createdOn").value</span>
  ```
- Update 2018-01-24

Play field is now returning a `Optional`, [see the docs](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/java/index.html). This means you can get the value from the field like:

- `@form("fieldName").getValue.get` (can throw a `NPE`)
- `@form("fieldName").getValue.getOrElse("defaultValue")`

Comment: I am using scala 2.0.3 and there is no field method. My code -> '@leaveform.field("status").value' and return error 'value field is not a member of play.api.data.Form[models.LeaveModel]'.

Comment: hmm.. I am using java, but the docs say: You also have access to the original field using @elements.field : http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaFormHelpers.

Comment: @SimonSiah try to use `@leaveform("status").value` instead, I have no experience with Scala Forms, anyway that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Flash context when returning a form to the user:

```
def create = withAuth { username => implicit request =>
        // leaveForm initialization as before

        // use form data from flash if present
        val form = if (flash.get("error").isDefined)
            leaveForm.bind(flash.data)
        else
            leaveForm
        Ok(stakeholders.register(form))
}

def insert = Action { implicit request =>
        leaveForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
                hasErrors = { form =>
                    Redirect(routes.Leaves.create).  // put correct route here
                        flashing(Flash(form.data) +
                            ("error" -> Messages("validation.errors"))) // customize error message
                },
                leave => {
                    LeaveModel.insert(leave)
                    Redirect(routes.indexController.index())
            }
        )
    }
```

HTH, Erich

Comment: This code work well during form creation and return error. 
@leaveform.forField("name")(value => value.value.get). Thanks for all the help guys.